What is the purpose of rounding bit in floating point numbers?
Let's only consider single precision ieee-754 floating point numbers. I understand how to convert decimal floating-point number to its ieee-754 representation (Well... almost). My problem is with rounding step. I've heard about guard, rounding, and sticky bits (a.k.a. GRS). I also found following explanation:

If the least significant bit is followed by a 0, then the number is nearer to the representable number whose absolute value is smaller. If the least significant bit is followed by an 1 and then there is another 1 in any position, the number is nearer to the number whose absolute value is greater. If the bit after the least significant bit is an 1 and there is not another 1 in any position afterwards, then the number is exactly between 2 representable numbers, and then the number is rounded so that there is a 0 in the least significant bit afterwards.


source: https://numeral-systems.com/ieee-754-add/

By my understanding there exist three scenarios:

G = 0 -> Truncation provides better approximation
G = 1 & S = 0 -> Truncation and rounding up provide same approximation
G = 1 & S = 1 -> Rounding up provides better approximation

So why is rounding bit implemented while guard and sticky bits could be enough?

I found a very similar question on StackOverflow. For people who have the same misunderstanding; please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79108779/why-do-we-need-both-a-round-bit-and-a-sticky-bit-in-ieee-754-floating-point-impl guard, round, or sticky bits are not specified in ieee-754 standard. This concept is meaningful when we are doing arithmetic operations on floating-point numbers.
